# View HTTPS on FIddler on Android

Tags: android, https, fiddler

I am trying to check which API an app is using and what data is being sent by the app.

I am using fiddler to intercept the data. However, I am unable to get what data is being sent. I assume this is because of HTTPS.

I am getting the following response in fiddler:
[image]

[image]

How can I get the see the request/response data?

And How can I secure my API so no one can view my data :-)

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the Fiddler documentation [here](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForAndroid). Basically, you need to

1. Route your traffic to use the Fiddler as a proxy
2. Install Fiddler's root certificate on your device's trusted list
3. Be on the same network as the computer which has Fiddler

Comment: I did that.. I am getting the urls in the list but when I view the data it doesn't show anything.